# How to dispatch an action in NgRx with parameters?

Tags: angular, ngrx

```
export enum ActionTypes {
  UpdateData = '[Data] Update Data',
}

export class UpdateData implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.UpdateData;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}
```

My Reducer:

```
export interface AppState {
  data: any;
}

const initialState: AppState = {
  data: null,
};

export function appReducer(state = initialState, action: Actions): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.UpdateData:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
import { UpdateData } from './store/actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="updateData()">Update Data</button>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  updateData() {
    // How do I pass parameters here to the action?
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateData(/* What to pass here? */));
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I pass parameters to the UpdateData action when dispatching it from the MyComponent? For example, let's say I want to update the data with a specific object or a string. How should I modify the updateData() function to achieve this?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or examples on how to handle this scenario properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `payload` is typed as `any` you can pass everything to it, but that probably will result in an invalid state. My first tip is to make it typed.

But to answer your question:

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateData({ propertyName: parameterValue });
```

See https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/you-should-take-advantage-of-the-improved-ngrx-apis#actions for the "new" and improved syntax of action in NgRx.